# is it possible to implement soap request as jax ws without wsdl

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, request, jax-ws

I have soap request format in XML. I want soap request implementation with jax ws without wsdl. So i can implement by sending XMLto service URL. Is it possible to do? If yes, then guild me to get solution.